# How to search from a start date and no end date?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I can search between dates, but if I want to just search from a start date and beyond.

I've been trying to teach myself VBA and SQL these past couple weeks... It's a working progress.

```
If Me.tb_dateRange1 <> "" And Me.tb_dateRange2 <> "" Then

    Dim LYear As Integer
    Dim thisDate As Date

    startDate = Me.tb_dateRange1
    endDate = Me.tb_dateRange2
    LYear = Year(endDate)

    If variationNumber = 0 Then
        sqlDateRange = " WHERE " & sqlDateRange
    Else
        sqlDateRange = " AND " & sqlDateRange
    End If

    'No end date conditions
    If endDate <> "" Then
        sqlDateRange = sqlDateRange & " Between #" & startDate & "# And #" & endDate & "#"
    Else
        'thisDate = #12/12/2223#
        sqlDateRange = sqlDateRange & " >= #" & startDate & "#"
    End If

    sqlMiddle = sqlMiddle & sqlDateRange
    variationNumber = variationNumber + 1
End If
```

Comment: I edited the code and it doesn't throw up an error anymore. Now nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your goal is to build a `WHERE` clause based on 2 text boxes, but only for those which contain values.

I didn't understand your code, so will offer you this approach which was tested with a sample form in Access 2007.

```vb
Const cstrFormat As String = "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#"
Dim strWhere As String

strWhere = vbNullString ' make it explicit
If IsDate(Me.tb_dateRange1) = True Then
    strWhere = "field_name >= " & Format(Me.tb_dateRange1, cstrFormat)
End If
If IsDate(Me.tb_dateRange2) = True Then
    ' add AND if we got something from the first text box
    If Len(strWhere) > 0 Then
        strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
    End If

    strWhere = strWhere & "field_name <= " & _
        Format(Me.tb_dateRange2, cstrFormat)
End If
If Len(strWhere) > 0 Then
    ' add WHERE
    strWhere = "WHERE " & strWhere
End If
```

Replace *field_name* with the name of your field.  If you need to evaluate time of day in addition to the date, change the format constant.

```vb
cstrFormat As String = "\#yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss\#"
```

I don't how you will be using the `WHERE` string, so I'll just display it in a `MsgBox`.

```vb
If Len(strWhere) > 0 Then
    MsgBox strWhere
Else
    MsgBox "no dates, so no WHERE"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to look for values that are **greater than or equal to** the startdate:

```
sqlDateRange = sqlDateRange & " >= #" & startDate & "#"
```

Access SQL is very particular about the date-formats it will accept:

```
sqlDateRange = sqlDateRange & " >= #" & Format(startDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
```

or, if necessary,

```
sqlDateRange = sqlDateRange & " >= #" & Format(startDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#"
```

(the ISO standard date notation)

Comment: I've edited with your suggestion, it's still not searching beyond the start date.

Comment: I've added to my answer.

Comment: If you are not getting results, maybe there is no qualifying data.  Run your query directly against the database before trying it in your application.